# Triangle inequality for a metric on the projective space

Tags: metric-spaces, projective-space

Define the following metric on $P(\mathbb{R}^2)$: 
For $\bar{x},\bar{y}\in P(\mathbb{R}^2)$ $(x=(x_1,x_2),y=(y_1,y_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2$), define

$$d(\bar{x},\bar{y})=\frac{|x_2 y_1-x_1 y_2|}{\|x\|\cdot \|y\|}$$

It is clear that $d(\bar{x},\bar{x})=0 \Longleftrightarrow x=0$, and $d(\bar{x},\bar{y})=d(\bar{y},\bar{x})$. Also, it is easy to see that it is well defined.

The only thing I am struggling with is the triangular inequality, I'm not sure how to approach it (the usual methods don't seem to work here).
How do you prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numerator is the magnitude of the cross product between the vectors, and the cross product is $\|x\|\|y\|\sin\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between them. ([Reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1378755/using-the-cross-product-to-find-the-angle-between-two-vectors-in-bbb-r3))

So the distance $d$ is simply the sine of the angle between two vectors. The angles are all between $0$ and $\pi$, so the sine is nonnegative. We can also box them in $[0, \pi/2]$, by picking the smaller of two complementary angles.

So, let $\alpha$ be the angle between $\bar x$ and $\bar y$, and $\beta$ the angle between $\bar y$ and $\bar z$; make sure that $\alpha,\beta\in [0, \pi/2]$. Then 
$$
|\sin(\alpha \pm \beta)| = |\sin\alpha \cos\beta \pm \cos\alpha \sin\beta|
\le \sin \alpha + \sin\beta
$$
Since the angle between $\bar x$ and $\bar z$ is given by either $\alpha+\beta$ or $\alpha-\beta$ or $\beta-\alpha$, the triangle inequality follows.